# Что означает (/.*)? в file_contexts?

Tags: linux, selinux

Во многих file_contexts вижу разное написание строк.
В одних пишется:

```
/dev/wmtWifi(/.*)?     u:object_r:wmtWifi_device:s0
```

В других:

```
/dev/wmtWifi           u:object_r:wmtWifi_device:s0
```

Что нам даёт данная строчка? В интернете описание этого не нашёл.

Comment: Первая строка выглядит как регулярное выражение, должна давать по идее указанный каталог и все его подкаталоги